# Load an image from an input stream in Python

Tags: python, image, file, input, stream

I am using Python Imaging Library to do some processing, and I'd like to feed my script with data through a pipe rather than passing a file name as an argument.

I've seen that `Image.open` can accept any file-like object besides a string as parameter. I've tried passing `sys.stdin` directly, but it seems that it is having some problems with `seek` (logically).

So, how can I wrap the stream into a buffer that provides all the file operations? (or other any suitable solution to read the image directly from `stdin`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html).

```
import StringIO
import sys

filelike = StringIO.StringIO(sys.stdin.read())

# Now use `filelike` as a regular open file, e.g.:
filelike.seek(2)
print filelike.read()
```

Comment: I had already find the solution and was about to auto-answer this very same, but thanks anyway! :-)